# Problema visual con Bootstrap

Tags: html, css, bootstrap

Tengo un problema con Bootstrap, lo que sucede es que en el sistema que estoy desarrollando tiene un menú que carga los formularios en la MasterPage pero si se da click en el `<li></li>` en el menú del formulario que ya está abierto, la pantalla se sube como si los elementos tuviesen un TOP -70 para explicarme mejor.

Esto no se soluciona recargando la página, solo si le doy back en el navegador se soluciona.

Comment: El punto que se ve ahí es un "li" solo que lo convirtió a lista

Comment: Ya lo edité, ahora se ve bien

Comment: Muchas gracias @César

Comment: De nada, tal vez puedas incluir el código HTML del cual hablas para que se más fácil ayudarte

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Sin algo de código es difícil pero me aventuraré a plantear la situación donde también estés usando jQuery donde podrías usar algo como:

```
$(document).ready(function (){
    // si son enlaces dentro del li debería haber un tag <a href="enlace">Texto</a> de lo contrario en la función siguiente reemplazar 'a' por 'li'
    $('a').on('click', function(e){
        e.preventDefault();
    });
});
```